# Dynamic image alignment with Javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic, alignment

I've got a Javascript curiosity that I must satisfy. Before I begin I should let you know that I am very aware of the fact that this can be handled with CSS alone, but I want to improve my Javascript skills so humor me :)

For reference to what I'm trying to get at: http://codepen.io/cmegown/pen/CGhpa

Let say we have a potentially infinite number of images, each wrapped inside of a figure set to display: inline-block so that it is the same size as the image inside. Each of these images can be any dimension, and the desired result is that the bottom of every image is perfectly aligned. The kicker here is that this is responsive, so the images may scale up or down. Here's my thinking of how this might be accomplished:

Loop through every image and find the tallest one (outerHeight), then grab that same image's width (outerWidth). Subtract the outerWidth from the outerHeight to get the "master" difference. Loop again through each image to calculate the difference for each specific image and subtract that from the "master" difference, then apply that number to the top margin. Rinse and repeat until each image is aligned to the bottom of the tallest image.

Right? I think the logic is sound, I just lack the skills to put this together properly in Javascript. Sorry for the super long post, but any and all help/advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
function alignImages() {

  // caching selectors
  var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img'),
      maxHeight = 0;
  for (idx in imgs) {
    var img = imgs[idx];
    if (img.height > maxHeight) {
      maxHeight = img.height;
    }
  }
  for (idx in imgs) {
    var img = imgs[idx];
    img.style.marginTop = (maxHeight - img.height) + "px";
  }


}
```

Comment: Very close, but I'm too much of a JS novice to figure out what is not working quite right here.

Comment: While this code works perfectly well in my pen linked above, when applied to the actual project the margins of each image compounds exponentially. Intuition tells me it has something to do with the knockout.js being used in the project, which is being used to perform many AJAX requests.

Comment: I still can't read minds to know if some conditions are not set in the question ;)

Comment: Quite right! I was very happy when it worked in the pen, and spent a few good hours today trying to solve the issue in-project. Any which way you spin it, I know more than I did before :)