# jQuery - get tallest image's height, apply other images' height difference to top margin

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each

I'm needing to loop through a series of images (number unknown) and get the tallest image's outerHeight value. Then I need to go through all the other images and get their outerHeight and subtract it from the tallest outerHeight, THEN apply that difference to that image's top margin. The end result will be all images bottom-aligned, and ***yes, I know this can be accomplished with CSS.*** Here's what I have so far:

**The HTML**

```
<ul class="hlist">
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="any-size.jpg" />
        </figure>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**The jQuery**

```
// This is what I have so far, most likely not right...
function createGrid() {
    var imgs = $('.hlist figure > img');
    var imgHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
    var maxImgHeight = 0;

    imgs.each(function () {
        maxImgHeight = maxImgHeight > imgHeight ? maxImgHeight : imgHeight;
    });
}
createGrid();
```

So I think `maxImgHeight` should have the tallest image's height at this point (not certain about that), but beyond this my lack of JS skills start to shine. I believe I need to loop through the images again and test each height against `maxImgHeight`, then apply that difference to the top margin.

Any help here would be hugely appreciated, especially if it was a well-commented and well-explained bit of help :) thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic image alignment with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17376409/dynamic-image-alignment-with-javascript)

Comment: It almost is, admittedly. Since that question was posted, I tried different variations of your answer - and it never quite worked for that specific scenario. I figured I would post a new/updated question with better code and descriptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function createGrid() {
    var imgs = $('.hlist figure > img');
    var maxImgHeight = 0;

    imgs.each(function () {
        var imgHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
        maxImgHeight = maxImgHeight > imgHeight ? maxImgHeight : imgHeight;
    });
    imgs.each(function () {
        var margin = maxImgHeight > $(this).outerHeight() ? (maxImgHeight - $(this).outerHeight()) : 0;
        $(this).css("margin-top", (margin + "px"));
    });
}
```

The first `each` loop looks for the tallest height and stores it in `maxImgHeight`, as you originally had planned. The second `each` loop calculates and applies the margin for each image. The conditional assignment will cause the `margin-top` for the tallest image to be 0.

Comment: Thanks much, sir! I understand the solution now, and this works ***perfectly*** in my project.

Answer (score 1):

```
function createGrid() {
    var imgs = $('.hlist figure > img'),
        maxImgHeight = 0;

    imgs.each(function () {
        var imgHeight = $(this).outerHeight(true);
        if (imgHeight > maxImgHeight) {
          maxImgHeight = imgHeight;
        }
    });
    imgs.each(function () {
        this.css('margin-top', (maxHeight - $(this).outerHeight(true)) + "px");
    });
}
createGrid();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this question too! Your fix for this part in my last question was close, but not quite right. I appreciate the help!